# Jquery not sending correct item id in Django

Tags: jquery, django

I'm trying to send some form data in django via ajax. the data i'm sending is the item id of objects. But when i'm making the ajax call it is not sending the correct item id. sometimes it is sending the id of the first item only.

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    msg = Message.objects.all()
    if request.POST.get('action')=="post":
        idi = request.POST.get('id')
        print(idi)
        ms = Message.objects.get(id = idi)
        print(ms)
        return render(request, "dashboard/contact.html", {"msg": msg, "ms": ms})
    return render(request, "dashboard/contact.html", {"msg": msg})
```

ajax

```
$(function() {
                    // Remove button click
                     $(document).on(
                        'click',
                        '.ida',
                        function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var pk = $(this).attr('value')
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: '{% url "contact" %}',
                                data: {
                                    id: pk,
                                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                                    action: "post",

                                },

                                success:function(){
                                    console.log(pk)
                                }

                            });
                        });
                 });
```

form

```
<form>
       {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{m.id}}" id="id">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success ida" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">View</button>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are misusing JQuery. You can use it like this. I think you are getting problem is based on value.

```
$('#id').change(function(){
    var pk = document.getElementById('id');
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", '{{ csrf_token }}');
    formData.append("pk", pk);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',           
        url : '{% url "contact" %}',
        dataType: "json",
        data : formData,
        success:function(){
            console.log(pk);
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: your solution is not posting the data in post method and refreshing the page everytime.

Comment: there are double commas at the end of url. That was the problem in your solution but now I'm getting 'illegal invocation error. Any help

Comment: It doesn't refreshes page every time. You can use returning data at success function. Where exactly do you get this error?